# Returning exceptions as JSON messages

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am developing an API with ASP.NET Core and I am struggling with the exception handling.

When any exception occurs, or in any controller where I want to return custom errors with different status codes,  I want to return JSON-formatted exception reports. I do not need HTML in the error response.

I'm not sure if I should use middleware for this, or something else. How should I return JSON exceptions in an ASP.NET Core API?

Comment: Sorry but "do not work" is a nonsense. Check the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please.

Comment: Sorry, wrote the question while trainriding. Will elaborate more on it when I am back at office.

Comment: @Hinrich I thought the question had potential for a good canonical answer, so I took the liberty of editing a little and proposing a solution. Feel free to roll back or edit further if you feel I changed the meaning of your question too much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error handling in ASP.NET Core 1.0 Web API (Sending ex.Message to the client)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38014379/error-handling-in-asp-net-core-1-0-web-api-sending-ex-message-to-the-client)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I got a working solution, that I am pretty happy with.

1. Add **middleware**:
   In the `Configure` Method, register the middleware (comes with ASP.NET Core).

   ```
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
   {
       // logging stuff, etc.

       app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/{0}");
       app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");

       app.UseMvc(); // if you are using Mvc

       // probably other middleware stuff 
   }
   ```
2. Create a Class for Messages
   Write a simple class that represents instances of **JSON Error Messages** you want to send as a request in any error case:

   ```
   public class ExceptionMessageContent
   {

       public string Error { get; set; }
       public string Message { get; set; }

   }
   ```
3. Create Error Controller
   add the **Error Controller** that handles all expected and unexpected errors. Note, that these routes correspond to the middleware configuration.

   ```
   [Route("[controller]")]
   public class ErrorController : Controller
   {

       [HttpGet]
       [Route("")]
       public IActionResult ServerError()
       {

           var feature = this.HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
           var content = new ExceptionMessageContent()
           {
               Error = "Unexpected Server Error",
               Message = feature?.Error.Message
           };
           return Content( JsonConvert.SerializeObject( content ), "application/json" );

       }


       [HttpGet]
       [Route("{statusCode}")]
       public IActionResult StatusCodeError(int statusCode)
       {

           var feature = this.HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
           var content = new ExceptionMessageContent() { Error = "Server Error", Message = $"The Server responded with status code {statusCode}" };
           return Content( JsonConvert.SerializeObject( content ), "application/json" );

       }
   }
   ```

Now, when I want to throw an error anywhere, I can just do that. The request gets redirected to the error handler and sends a `500` with a nice formatted error message. Also, `404` and other codes are handled gracefully. Any custom status codes I want to send, I can also return them with an instance of my `ExceptionMessageContent`, for example:

```
// inside controller, returning IActionResult

var content = new ExceptionMessageContent() { 
    Error = "Bad Request", 
    Message = "Details of why this request is bad." 
};

return BadRequest( content );
```

Answer (score 12):

An exception filter (either as an attribute, or a global filter) is what you are looking for. From the [docs](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/controllers/filters.html#exception-filters):

> Exception filters handle unhandled exceptions, including those that occur during controller creation and model binding. They are only called when an exception occurs in the pipeline. They can provide a single location to implement common error handling policies within an app.

If you want **any** unhandled exception to be returned as JSON, this is the simplest method:

```
public class JsonExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        var result = new ObjectResult(new
        {
            code = 500,
            message = "A server error occurred.",
            detailedMessage = context.Exception.Message
        });

        result.StatusCode = 500;
        context.Result = result;
    }
}
```

You can customize the response to add as much detail as you want. The ObjectResult will be serialized to JSON.

Add the filter as a global filter for MVC in Startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(typeof(JsonExceptionFilter));
    });
}
```

Comment: This handles all my uncatched failures, which is a good start. Thx. But what if I wanted to return a `BadRequest` or any other status code from a controller programmatically?

Comment: note, that Exception filters handle only MVC exceptions, more generic approach in ASP.NET Core is to use ExceptionHandler middleware: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/asp.net-core/1479/middleware/4815/using-the-exceptionhandler-middleware-to-send-custom-json-error-to-client#t=201608011043382097082

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using ASP.NET Middleware with `ProblemDetails`.  You could use an ExceptionFilter as was also suggested but that is more of an "old-school" pattern - though either work.

This solution uses both `ProblemDetails` [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.problemdetails) and the RFC [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807) as well as [Ben Adams' Exception Demystifier nuget](https://github.com/benaadams/Ben.Demystifier)

```
public class CustomExceptionMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public CustomExceptionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _next = next ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(next));
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }

    [SuppressMessage("Design", "CA1062:Validate arguments of public methods",
        Justification = "This might result in a stack overflow if we throw an exception in middleware designed to handle exceptions")]
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);

            // Don't log it here - we have other middleware that handles that - see CustomLoggingMiddleware
            await HandleExceptionAsync(httpContext, ex);
        }
    }

    [SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "PossibleNullReferenceException", Justification = "params will never be null")]
    private Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
    {
        if (exception == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(exception));
#if DEBUG
        // The middleware shouldn't ever be called thru a HostedService - e.g. Hangfire scheduled jobs, but just in case....
        Debug.Assert(context != null, "HttpContext is null - is this error from a Hangfire job?");
#else
        if (context == null) return Task.CompletedTask;
#endif
        var errorStatusCode = exception is UnauthorizedAccessException ||
                                exception is SecurityTokenException ?
            StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized : StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;

        context.Response.ContentType = "application/problem+json";
        context.Response.StatusCode = errorStatusCode;

        var instanceMessage = $"{CorrelationIdOptions.DefaultHeader}: {context.GetCorrelationId()}";

        //don't show full details unless we're running LOCAL environment!
        string errorDetail;

        if (_hostingEnvironment.IsLocal())
        {
            // ApiException's ToString override calls ToStringDemystified(), so call the ApiException ToString() override
            errorDetail = exception is ApiException ? exception.ToString() : exception.ToStringDemystified();
        }
        else
        {
            errorDetail = "The instance value should be used to identify the problem when contacting customer support";
        }

        var errorDetailsJson = new ProblemDetails
        {
            Detail = errorDetail,
            Instance = instanceMessage,
            Status = errorStatusCode,
            Title = Constants.UnhandledExceptionTitle
        };

        return context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonSerializer.Serialize(errorDetailsJson));
    }
}
```