# ASP.NET Core WebApi return error message to AngularJS $http promise

Tags: angularjs, error-handling, asp.net-core-mvc, angular-promise

I would like to return exception message to the AngularJS UI.
As a back-end I use ASP.NET Core Web Api controller:

```
    [Route("api/cars/{carNumber}")]
    public string Get(string carNumber)
    {
        var jsonHttpResponse = _carInfoProvider.GetAllCarsByNumber(carNumber);
        if (jsonHttpResponse.HasError)
        {
            var message = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(jsonHttpResponse.ErrorMessage)
            };

            throw new HttpResponseException(message);
        }

        return jsonHttpResponse.Content;
    }
```

But on Angular side, failure promise sees only status and statusText "Internal server error":

[image]

How can I pass the error message to the Angular $http failure promise from Core Web Api?

Comment: You return `HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError` in this code, which is HTTP 500. Instead, you should figure out what error is in `jsonHttpResponse` and set `message` to that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you're doing some [exception filtering](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/controllers/filters.html#exception-filters), `throw new HttpResponseException(message)` is going to become an uncaught exception, which will be returned to your frontend as a generic 500 Internal Server Error.

What you should do instead is return a status code result, such as `BadRequestResult`. This means that instead of returning a string, your method needs to return `IActionResult`:

```
[Route("api/cars/{carNumber}")]
public IActionResult Get(string carNumber)
{
    var jsonHttpResponse = _carInfoProvider.GetAllCarsByNumber(carNumber);
    if (jsonHttpResponse.HasError)
    {
        return BadRequest(jsonHttpResponse.ErrorMessage);
    }

    return Ok(jsonHttpResponse.Content);
}
```

See also: my answer on [how to return uncaught exceptions as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38664740/3191599). (If you want *all* uncaught exceptions to be returned as JSON, instead.)

Comment: But what if it's not a bad request? You might get an exception from your backend and that would warrant a 500 (internal server error).

Comment: @DanielPrzybylski In that case, you can always throw an exception (or allow an uncaught one to bubble up), which results in `500 Internal Server Error` being sent to the client. Or, you can return status code 500 yourself.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing already, I'm just not sure when that isn't included as a convenient method. Also, I'm wondering how to embed messages in the HttpResponse the way the HttpResponseException did it in .NET 4.x.