# Error while returning HttpResponseMessage in.NET core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, stream, httpresponsemessage

I have a simple API gateway controller which returns an `IActionResult`. The issue is I am not able to read the body of the response.

If I comment out the using block in `ExecuteResultAsync` it seems to work fine but there is not content/body.

Not sure how to get this working with the httpbody being returned. RouteRequest returning `HttpResponseMessage` is not an option as it puts the response from the microservice as the body of the response from the Gateway.

So I need to use the `HttpResponseMessageResult` middleware, which works as expected for headers but not for the body.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> RouteRequest()
{
    // Calls a method which send a request and gets a response and constructs a HttpResponseMessage         
    _contextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.RegisterForDispose(response);    
    return new HttpResponseMessageResult(response);        
}       


public class HttpResponseMessageResult : IActionResult
{
    private readonly HttpResponseMessage _responseMessage;

    public HttpResponseMessageResult(HttpResponseMessage responseMessage)
    {
        _responseMessage = responseMessage;
    }

    public async Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)_responseMessage.StatusCode;

        var responseMessageHeadersArray = _responseMessage.Headers.ToArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < responseMessageHeadersArray.Length; i++)
        {
            var header = responseMessageHeadersArray[i];
            context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.TryAdd(header.Key, new StringValues(header.Value.ToArray()));
        }

        using (var stream = await _responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        {
            await stream.CopyToAsync(context.HttpContext.Response.Body);
            await context.HttpContext.Response.Body.FlushAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, based on [this good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42594823/7595191) to a similar question, I used the `ObjectResult` class instead of manually manipulating the streams.  When I run it with response from one of our API's (JSON), I get the same amount of data in the body of `objectResult` when it calls `ExecuteAsync` as were in the initial response.

```
public class HttpResponseMessageResult : IActionResult
{
    private readonly HttpResponseMessage _responseMessage;
    public HttpResponseMessageResult(HttpResponseMessage responseMessage)
    {
        _responseMessage = responseMessage;
    }

    public async Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    {
        var objectResult = new ObjectResult(await _responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        {StatusCode = (int)_responseMessage.StatusCode};
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>> h in _responseMessage.Headers)
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.TryAdd(h.Key, string.Join("", h.Value));
        }

        await objectResult.ExecuteResultAsync(context);
    }
}
```