# Custom IActionResult method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, httpresponsemessage

In a WebApi2 project I could create a custom action response a bit like this:

```
public class TestResult : IHttpActionResult
{
    private readonly int id;

    public TestResult (int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(Execute());
    }

    private HttpResponseMessage Execute()
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Accepted; 
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri($"xxx\{id}");
        response.Content = new ObjectContent<Test>(new Test { TestNumber = id }, mediaType));
        return response;
    }
}
```

This sets the response content and location on the header.

How do I do this in .Net core?

The `IActionResult` result interface only has 1 method:
`Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)`

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried inheriting from `ObjectResult`? You can pass a value and override the default behavior, then calling the base `ExecuteResultAsync`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write custom actionResult in asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594356/how-to-write-custom-actionresult-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: @PeterCsala No it doesn't as that doesn't set the location and I don't seem to have that option

Comment: @ColinM How to set the location though?

Comment: @Sun you set the Location header, via `actionContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers` dictionary, within the `ExecuteResultAsync` method.

Comment: @ColinM Thank you