# How do I format response data into ASP.NET CORE?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have existing `ASP.Net WEB API` with below output response format , 
I'm converting that project into `ASP.NET CORE`.

I have already gone through this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/formatting)

```
public class MyClass
{       
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }       
}

// Helper.cs
public class ApiResponse
{
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "data")]
    public object Data { get; set; }

    public ApiResponse(HttpStatusCode statusCode, object result = null)
    {
        Data = result;
    }
}

// Helper.cs
public class WrappingHandler<T> where T : class
{
    public static HttpResponseMessage ResponseHandler(IEnumerable<T> responseObject, HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, responseObject);
        var newResponse = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new ApiResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, responseObject));
        return newResponse;
    }
}

// HomeController.cs

public HttpResponseMessage RetriveData(string name)
{
    try
    {
        var mydata = _context.Get(name);
        return WrappingHandler<MyClass>.ResponseHandler(mydata, Request);
    }
}

// output for asp.net webapi 
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 32,
            "name": "Hi everyone" 
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I'm converting the project to `ASP.NET CORE` so I need to change the return type as well from `HttpResponseMessage` to `IActionResult or`JsonResult` but how do I manage my custom output format changes?

I mean what changes I need to do into `WrappingHandler` and `ApiResponse`       anyhelp?

Comment: Why do you need `WrappingHandler`? Why not return the response directly from the action?

Comment: `WrappingHandler` i'm doing some formating like I want result into `data` and also adding few more extra fields like `metadata` into output. thats why using WrappingHandler and doing formatting. it works perfect into asp.net webapi but how to use/make these chnages into asp.net core return response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing different things.

Regarding result that controller action should return (from [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/formatting)):

> An action isn't required to return any particular type; MVC supports any object return value. If an action returns an `IActionResult` implementation and the controller inherits from Controller, developers have many helper methods corresponding to many of the choices. Results from actions that return objects that are not `IActionResult` types will be serialized using the appropriate `IOutputFormatter` implementation.

`IActionResult` is just an interface that defines following contract:

```
Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
```

And yes, ASP.NET Core provides a lot of predefined classes for different purpose:

- simple `StatusCodeResult` or more specific classes like `OkResult`, `NotFoundResult`, etc
- for particular format: `JsonResult`, `ContentResult`, etc..

So you are free to select what is more suitable for your case.

---

Regarding the `WrappingHandler` replacement -it is the controller action main responsibility to create a response. Others better should work with data model only. In other words, your `WrappingHandler` class should be some kind of service with only something like this:

```
public class DataService
{ 
   public MyClass RetriveData(string name)
   {
      var mydata = _context.Get(name);
      return mydata
   }
 }
```

- If you want to format the final response, like adding custom headers, consider using the MVC Filters, in particular - [ResultFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#result-filters).
- If you need some generic response validation - use [ActionFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#action-filters), d [ExceptionFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#Exception-filters) or [ExceptionHandler middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38014379/2833802). In other words, if above `RetriveData` method may raise exceptions and you do not want to have 200 OK as a response in this case - this is not the `DataService` class responsibility to handle this logic.

Comment: good one got you but what about response format like add key for output response ` "data": [` or add more fields like `data` in output json?

Comment: @Neo Consider this as part of data Model (MyClass) or response Model (ApiResponse) modification. My main points are that logic like `new ApiResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, <MyClass instance>)` should be in controller action. And then using filters you may modify/replace `ApiResponse` instance if needed.