# ASP.NET Core 2 MVC Global Exception Handling not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET Core 2 MVC application. I try to figure out how global exception handling in `Startup.cs` works.

So far so good, I can use the regular `app.UseStatusCodePages()` middleware.

Nevertheless, when I try to use the `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute` to show the HTTP status code on my view, I only get a standard HTTP 500 page and there is no redirect to my `CustomError` action in my Error controller.

For demo purpose, I run my app in **Production** Environment, not in Development.

I throw my error in my ValuesController. The ValuesController looks like that:

```
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int id)
    {
        throw new Exception("Crazy Error occured!");
    }
}
```

My `Startup.cs` looks like that:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // Global Exception Handling, I run in Production mode
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else // I come into this branch
    {
        //app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error/Error");

        // My problem starts here: I cannot redirect to my custom error method... 
        //there is only a standard http 500 screen
        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/CustomError/{0}");
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Values}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Finally, my ErrorController looks like that:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult CustomError(string code)
    {
        // I only want to get here in debug, to get the code
        // unfortunately it never happens :/
        return Content("Error Test");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot redirect to my CustomError method and get the HTTP status code according to the exception.

There is only a standard chrome HTTP 500 page, thus nothing works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Status Code Pages Middleware doesn't work with unhandled exceptions during pipeline execution but checks the **response** status code (for responses without bodies).

If you modify action method to something like this, you will get the custom error page:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int id)
 {
    return new StatusCodeResult(500);
 }
```

For exceptions handling look into `UseExceptionHandler` method. For example:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error/CustomError/500");
```

Note, you can use both `UseExceptionHandler` and `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute` in your app.

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly when I return the StatusCodeResult... Hm, but how can i catch Runtime exceptions without using a try catch in MVC? :)

Comment: @TimHorton if you want to catch exceptions in MVC middleware only, use [Exception Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#exception-filters). If for all pipeline exception, then use another version of ExceptionHandler: `app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp => { errorApp.Run(async context => ... ) }` (check [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38014379/error-handling-in-asp-net-core-1-0-web-api-sending-ex-message-to-the-client/38015155#38015155) for sample). And of course, you always may write your own middleware for global try-catch